# Recent Google Docs gone after uninstalling & reinstalling the app

Tags: google-docs

I uninstalled Google Docs on my android phone yesterday evening to make space for updating WhatsApp, then reinstalled Google Docs half an hour later. Didn't think anything of it as it all backs up into Google Drive.

However, all my recent documents (everything after December 2018) are gone! They are nowhere to be found, not even in Google Drive!

How can this be? I can see in my backups that Docs' was last backup was on May 8th. However, not sure how to access that. Please help!

Comment: how about here: https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/

Comment: I'm afraid not.. :(

Answer (score 0):

The normal process of uninstalling the Android app doesn't has any effect on the documents saved on the Google cloud.

On the Google Drive web app and/or the Google Documents web app first you should check if you are looking at the right account, then check if the files are on the trash, then check if they are orphaned files and lastly ask for support from a Google Drive specialist by using the Contact Us button on the [Google Drive Help Center](https://support.google.com/drive) before 90 days after the files were deleted otherwise the specialist will not be able to recover your files.